# Normalizer of Normalizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, sylow-theory

I know that, given a finite group group $G$ with Sylow $p$ subgroup $S$, $N_G(S)=N_G(N_G(S))$.  I cannot think of how I would find a subgroup $H$ such that $N_G(H)$ is a proper subset of $N_G(N_G(H))$.  What is a way to think of such an example?

Comment: Hint: Try a $p$-group and any non-normal subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nilpotent group fulfills the normalizer condition: any proper subgroup is always **strictly contained** in its normalizer, Well, now just choose a non-normal subgroup there...

For an easy example, choose a finite non-abelian $\;p\,-$ group which is not the quaternions (since any subgroup here is normal...).